# Strange dull areas on paintwork after trip to bodyshop

Tags: paint

After a crash I had some work done to my car at an Audi approved bodyshop. This involved some respraying.

Since I've got it back I've noticed dull matte marks on one side of the paintwork. They seem to be in a line.

I can't imagine they would have been there before. I would have spotted them.

Does anyone know what this could be? I'm stumped.

Comment: Picture please.

Comment: A photo would really help. A close up would be good, especially with something for size reference, as would some overall photos to let us see where the marks are relative to the damage and the work that was done. My first thought are overspray or areas that got missed when polishing.

Answer (score 2):

The problem would most likely be overspray and/or not finishing correctly. If there is a top clear coat and this wasn't cut/polished correctly, it could leave something like what you're talking about. This would be especially true if there was overspray somewhere which was not caught during the final finishing steps.

You need to take this back to the place which did the work and have them fix it. Most every place which deals through insurance companies have warranties on their work. If they don't (or won't) fix it, they may not be able to get any more work from the insurance company. Just tell them it is something you noticed after you retrieved the vehicle. If they don't want to do it, inform them you'll be calling your insurance company about it. This usually gets their attention. More than likely though, it was just an oversight, though it could have been a lazy finisher as well.